# Why won't my controller action fire in my Action Link using data-toggle tab

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here is what I am trying to accomplish, I am trying to get my @Html.ActionLink to perform 2 functions, 1 I would like it to refresh the data on the page by calling the controller in the action link. 2. I would like to activate the Data-toggle to switch between tabs in the tabble content. This is my @Html.ActionLink

Note: the toggle works great, but I cannot get action in the controller to fire. this has to be possible since I found this solution on Stack.

```
<li class="active">@Html.ActionLink("Registered", "CommunitiesLanding", "home", new { id = 0 }, new { href = "#tab1", data_toggle = "tab" })</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Certified", "CommunitiesLanding", "home", new { id = 1 }, new { href = "#tab2", data_toggle = "tab" })</li>
```

in the Markup this is what the MVC renders:

```
<li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Registered</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Certified</a></li>
```

Comment: You're overriding the URL with `#tab1` or `#tab2`.  The link has either one value or another, it can't have both.  You either perform an action client-side, *or* submit a request to the server.  Can't be both.

Comment: do you have any suggestions

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to accomplish.  Maybe you can have client-side code respond to the tab change to perform an AJAX request to the server.  Then you'd update the page data client-side.

Comment: I think I may try to do this by controlling the tab function using the model instead of a data-toggle

Comment: Thank you for your response